# Why in chainer define self define function backward function must return gradient shape the same as input?

Tags: chainer

Two questions:

1. https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/tutorial/function.html written: the backward function must return the same shape as the arguments of the forward method? because in some cases, the input data and parameter need not to be same shape or length, such as Convolutional2D, How to deal with input data and parameter have different shape.
2. because in some cases, such as maxpooling, there is no gradient here. How to define such chainer function?

Answer (score 0):

1. The `backward` method should return a tuple of arrays, and the i-th array of the tuple should have the same shape as the i-th argument of the `forward` method. Of course, the different arguments of `forward` (and thus different return values of `backward`) can have different shapes.
2. When a function does not have gradient w.r.t. some of the inputs (i.e., the gradient is always zero), you can return `None` as the corresponding elements of the tuple instead of zero-filled arrays. By the way, max pooling does have gradients.

Comment: about 2nd question: Do you mean if forward function has a,b,c argument, if b does not have gradient, I write backward return (ga, None, gc) tuple, here ga, gc means gradient of f wrt. a and  c.?

Comment: One more question: if I want to write a layer, the backward of this layer which flow gradient should do in the layer's membership function, the layer itself does not have backward() function . am I understand right?

Comment: For the first comment: yes, you can return `(ga, None, gc)` to indicate that the function has no gradient w.r.t. `b`.

Comment: For the second comment: do you mean Link by "layer"? If so, basically yes. If you manually stop the gradient flow without changing Function definitions, you can also write `x = Variable(x.data)` or `x.unchain()` to cut the computational graph at `x` (the former does not modify the existing object, while the latter does).

Comment: if w and x shape are different(like conv layer or other layer), thus dw and dx shape are different, how can we element-wise top-layer's dx multiply by the previous-layer's dw that affect the change of w of this previous layer.